# Assign console.log to a var

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get password from a json file with below code.

Now the password is shown in console.
How can I assign it to a var？

```html
fetch('assets/pwd.json')
          .then(response => {
            return response.json()
          })
          .then(data => {
           console.log((data.password[0]))
          })
```

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: This might help as well. https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch('assets/pwd.json')
          .then(response => {
            return response.json()
          })
          .then(data => {
           var password = data.password[0]
           console.log(password)
          })
```

You can first save the data to a variable, and then you can console log it... It's that simple

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do `var pass=data.password[0];`